# Need help understanding diagnostic report for a potential purchase

Tags: honda, crv, inspection

I am interested in buying a Honda CR-V 2014 AWD and we took the car to an inspection agency. There were a few issues based on the inspection and I am not sure how to move forward with the sale. The owner was asked to change the engine oil right after inspection, as well as replace the gasket due to an axle leakage.

The following are translated into English since I am in a country with a different language. The approximate price of the vehicle is $14,330.

- Gear: Transition is fine. Check oil and filter. The oil leak was fixed with no warranty
- Differential: Slight emptiness
- Chassis: Good
- Front body: Bushing was replaced, slight tire shake, Brake Discs are slightly shot.
- Structure/frame: Trunk was painted, there’s a slight percentage of body paste repairs. Keep in mind, the fibre part of the trunk was not inspected.
- Double gear: good
- Front Differential: good, leak was fixed
- Notes: Gears are making noise, check the thermostat, the engine was fixed, something is leaking front the front axle and the rest need to be washed so they can tell.

My question here is, should I bother continuing with the sale? Should I ask the seller to fix these first or will the car not be safe to drive in the near future?

What else should I be considering based on the inspection report?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a very detailed report.  Perhaps a better translation for the brakes is "slightly worn"?  Because "shot" implies they are totally worn and no good at all.  Is such an inspection common where you are?

Comment: It was my idea to have the car inspected before proceeding with the transaction and this is the most reputable place in the country. The brakes will probably need to be replaced soon so yes, a better translation will be that they are slightly worn.

Comment: "Slightly Shot" to me would mean *just this side of worn out*. This report, while covering a lot of turf, seems very subjective.

Comment: Just so people realize, I don't think this is off topic. The gist of the question is asking about the inspection report and how to interpret it.

Answer (score 1):

If the differential is "slightly empty" but there is no visible leak, it's a cause for concern. The only reason it should be "slightly empty" is due to a leak. Is it possible that somebody tried to cover up a leak by removing the evidence?

Tire shake might be a problem. Why on earth would the tires be shaking? Presumably they are incorrectly balanced. The same is true of the brake discs: you may need to change them.

I wouldn't choose a car with body paste repairs, especially if the car is a 2014 model. On some beater car, this may be acceptable.

Noisy gears might be very expensive to repair, because the gearbox may be shot.

If something is leaking from the front axle as well, in addition to all the existing problems, I would not buy the car. A 2014 model should be in much better condition. Of course, I cannot comment on the price: prices of used cars vary from place to place depending on the tax levels of new cars.

The car may be safe to drive, but these problems will haunt you in the future. Buy something else instead!

Comment: Thanks for the opinion. I got cold feet after seeing the report, but since this is the first time I am buying a car, I figured to ask for some advice first.